# Run user installed binary in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, path

Unlike as in Terminal, I cannot run a binary (which I installed through package manager) from a bash script without knowing its path. So far I've been using a method to determine that which feels rather clumsy.

```
APP=(
    "/usr/bin/my_app"
    "/usr/local/bin/my_app"
    "/opt/local/bin/my_app"
    "/bin/my_app"
    )

for i in ${APP[*]}; do

    if [[ -e $i ]]; then
        eval $i $@
        break
    else
        echo "$i not found"
    fi
done
```

There's got to be a better way than this, right? I already tried `APP=$(which my_app)`, but it reports "command not found".

Comment: That doesn't sound normal. You're not overwriting `$PATH` anywhere in the script are you? How is the script being executed?

Comment: Didn't think this would matter, but the script is called by Sublime Text to build an open file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically duplicating the shell's built-in functionality. Use the built-in features instead.

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/bin:$PATH
# ... though /usr/local/bin should normally go before /usr/bin
hash -r my_app # just to be safe
my_app "$@"
```

Also, the `eval` is superfluous, and the `$@` needs to be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The binary needs to be in your `$PATH` and it needs to be executable.

Do an `ls -l /path/to/your/my_app` do ensure that the executable bit is set.

If you're launching Sublime Text from a menu bar, the application will need to be in your system path, not just the path in your current bash shell. You could need to update `/etc/profile` to do that. But the easiest thing to start to test the path theory is to make a symlink to your application in a directory known to be always in the path. e.g. `ln -s /crazy/path/to/your/my_app /usr/bin/` . If that works, then you know it's a PATH issue.